# htaccess subdomain rewrite to variable without being visible in the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to convert "subdomains" to variables using htaccess.
But I don't want the original url to be displayd after the rewrite.

Here's what I have so far:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.mysite.\com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1?aff=%1 [nc]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

What I need is the following:

User links to:
`aff1.mysite.com`

The displayed url changes to:
`www.mysite.com/`

But the actual url that the server reads is:
`www.mysite.com/?aff=aff1`

I'm also going to be adding languages to the mix, so I might even need something like the following:

User links to: `aff1.mysite.com`

Then I get the language from a cookie `{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([A-Za-z]+)$`

If there's nothing in the cookie, the default should be "`en`"

Then the user gets redirected to `aff1.en.mysite.com`

Which should then be displayed as: `www.mysite.com/en/`

but to the server: `www.mysite.com/?lang=en&aff=aff1`

Please tell me this is possible, and how I can achieve this.  I'm very new to rewriting.  And I've viewed other questions and tried their solutions, but somehow can't adapt it to exactly what I need.

Also... `www.mysite.com` shouldn't go to `www.mysite.com/aff=www`

It should just go to `/mysite.com/en/`

Answer (score 0):

So, I've spent way more time than I wanted to on this, but finally got something working.  Instead of passing the variables in the url, I'm dropping a cookie (which was ultimately what I was doing on the page anyway, but this cuts out a step - and I didn't know that you could drop cookies with the rewrite).

If anyone has a better solution with less lines of code, please feel free to comment or post a new answer.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.info [nc] #if url starts with www.example.info
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.info/$1 [r,nc] #rewrite without the www

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.(.*).example.info [nc] #if url starts with www.(aff).example.info
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.info/$1 [r,nc] #rewrite without the www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.*)\.example.info [nc] #if subdomain is aff
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [co=aff:%1:example.info:7200:/] #drop/update cookie with aff

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.*)\.example.info [nc] #if subdomain is aff
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.info/$1 [nc,R,L] #rewrite without subdomain
```